# Nesting and retrieving variables for each slide in Slider Revolution plugin via API

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, revolution-slider

I need a little help with my Slider Revolution.

I would like to attach a string to each slide and then retrieve on the onchange event.

I've added the string in Slide's description field (see illustration):
jQuery('#slideid').bind("revolution.slide.onchange",function (e,data) {
});

The question is, how do I fetch this data from the data object in "revolution.slide.onchange" event?

Here is the site (password:1958): http://sommergallery.wwwnlsrc4.supercp.com

Thanks in advance,
Sasha

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: Please do not post the links which is not accicible for longer time. we can't help without [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).